# MySQL conditional order for column with empty values

Tags: mysql

My db has product rows, which all have a `price`, and some have a `discounted_price`. Where there isn't a discount, the `discounted_price` is null.

What kind of a query would sort the items from lowest to highest price so that the discounted products would be sorted by the `discounted_price`, the rest by the `price`?

Here's my best guess, which does not work:

```
SELECT product_title, discounted_price, price FROM products
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN discounted_price IS NOT NULL THEN discounted_price
        WHEN discounted_price IS NULL THEN price
    END ASC
```

Comment: `order by coalesce(discounted_price, price)`?

Comment: Instead of ordering them and then still having to check both values, why not just put the non-null lower of the two into the field?

Comment: @MarcB already gave the answer of course, but as a suggestion, maybe it's better to store the price and the non-discounted price. That way, you can just sort by price. This will help you not only in showing your products from low to high price, but also when you want to calculate a total for an order. The price column is the actual price, discounted or not, and the original non-discounted price (if any) is stored in another column just for reference.

Comment: As the system is quite large, I can't/won't modify the whole db structure. But @MarcB's answer did the trick!